# Get Full Html from page after it is rendered

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a UserControl which I want to extract the HTML from, so that I can convert the html to PDF. The page has already been rendered at the point this needs to happen, so I'd like to stay away from `RenderControl` if possible.

I'd also like to do it all server side. I know I could extract all of the html via javascript and ajax it to the server but I'd rather do it server side.

Is there any way to do this without intercepting/overriding Render?

Comment: What's wrong with `RenderControl`?

Comment: Why are you opposed to calling `RenderControl`?

Comment: @Candide I don't want to use it because at the time this needs to happen, the control is already rendered. I just want to grab the html afterwards.

Comment: Afterwards is too late. You have to do it during rendering.

Comment: @Dai ^ (stupid character minimum)

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt You can still create a new instance of that user control and call render on it again.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Ok, I guess I'll do that then. I just didn't want to do that, because usually I won't need the html. It'll only be when the user clicks an "Email" link. I guess itd be really inexpensive to just capture the html before sending it back to the client, but I didn't want to do it every time just because I felt like it'd be the "right" thing to do. Thanks

Comment: @Candide yeah -- but there's some context stuff involved, and I didn't want to really add that much work to the server. Just wanted to keep it as simple as possible. I guess I was basically looking for a server side way to query the DOM, but upon rethinking it, thats going to be impossible. I'll just do it client side